# Iterate over large list of lists and replace its elements

Tags: python, beginner, performance

I have a large list of lists, where each list contains words/characters as elements, and each list is of different length and may contain same words/characters more than once, as for example:

```
list_ = [['black', 'window', 'says', 'window'], ['dog', 'great'], ['after', 'end', 'explains', 'income', '.', '?']]
```

I also have a large dictionary of words/characters like this:

```
dictionary = {'word1': 'RARE', 'word2': 'RARE', 'word3': 'RARE', '%': 'RARE'} etc.
```

The length of `list_` is around 40 000 (the total number of words in all lists is about 1 mln) and the length of `dictionary` is around 31 000. For each word in `dictionary`, I need to check if it's in any of the lists of `list_` and if it is, I need to replace it with 'RARE'.

For example, if `'black'== 'word1'` and `'after' == word3`, the final `list_` will be:

```
list_ = [['RARE', 'window', 'says'], ['dog', 'says'], ['RARE', 'end', 'explains', 'income']]
```

Because of the large length of `list_` and `dictionary`, the code that I currently have below takes almost 40min to run. I'm new to Python and I would appreciate if someone could suggest whether there's a way to do this task much faster/more efficiently.

```
def replace_all(word_list, dictionary):
   for i, j in dictionary.iteritems():
      for lst in word_list: 
         if i in set(lst): 
            lst[lst.index(i)] = j

replace_all(list_, dictionary)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping in incorrect order, take the advantage of the fact that [dictionary provides `O(1)` lookups](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). So, you should loop over the list and replace its items with the value present in the dictionary. This way you will loop over the list only once:

We can either use `dict.get` here and avoid an `if` condition:

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
   for lst in word_list:
      for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
          lst[ind] = dictionary.get(item, item)
```

Or check for the key first and modify only matched item([LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)):

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
   for lst in word_list:
      for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
          if item in dictionary:
              lst[ind] = dictionary[item]
```

or if you prefer [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) then try to catch the `KeyError`:

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
   for lst in word_list:
      for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
          try:
              lst[ind] = dictionary[item]
          except KeyError:
              pass
```

---

I generally find functions that modify a mutable item in-place and don't return anything confusing, it's usually a better idea to return the list object from the function and re-assign to the variable from where it was called.

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
   for lst in word_list:
      for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
          lst[ind] = dictionary.get(item, item)

list_ = replace_matched_items(list_, dictionary)
```

But the above approach is still flawed(at least when our object has multiple references), with this even though we re-assigned only a single variable all the other references to the list object will still be affected, which can be very confusing to users. For example:

```
def func(seq):
    for lst in seq:
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            if x == 1:
                lst[i] = 100
    return seq

foo = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
dct = {'key': foo}

foo = func(foo)
print foo
print dct
```

Outputs:

```
[[100, 100, 2], [100, 2, 3]]
{'key': [[100, 100, 2], [100, 2, 3]]}
```

To fix such such cases we can either pass a [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of the list to the function(or simple shallow copy for list containing only immutable items) or we can create a new list inside of the function. But as we are dealing with 1 million items creating another list will surely result in extra memory consumption. Here's an example of how to do this by creating a new list using `dict.get`:

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
    new_list = [[dictionary.get(item, item) for item in lst] for lst in word_list]
    return new_list

list_ = replace_matched_items(list_, dictionary)
```

Few other questions on the same topic:

- [Is making in-place operations return the object a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062423/is-making-in-place-operations-return-the-object-a-bad-idea)
- [Why does django ORM's `save` method not return the saved object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936737/why-does-django-orms-save-method-not-return-the-saved-object/10936874)

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary, thanks a lot for all your suggestions,  this was incredibly helpful! I tried it and your code takes only a sec to run!

Comment: On a related note, if you are looking for in-place replacements within a list, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24203748/307454)